# Defining an anchor name within my preference pane

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, system-preferences, nspreferencepane

I would like enable AppleScript to reveal a particular tab within a custom preference pane I am developing, so that this works:

```
tell application "System Preferences" 
  reveal anchor "Foo" of pane id "com.example.preferences.Bar"
end tell
```

I cannot find anywhere how my preference pane would declare or specify the `"Foo"` anchor or associate that with any particular tab view item.

Comment: Google GPGPreferences.searchTerms dictionary revealElementForKey for some clues… (AFAIK this isn't documented anywhere…)

Comment: Also search developer.apple.com for NSPrefPaneHelpAnchors… (hope this helps… ;-)

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer contact Apple's Developer Technical Support (<https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action#techSupport>) for an "official" answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that comes to this question with the amount of frustration I did, I'm documenting here the steps to be able to get anchors for your custom `NSPreferencePane`.

The greatest hint was from @geowar:

> Google GPGPreferences.searchTerms dictionary revealElementForKey for some clues… (AFAIK this isn't documented anywhere…)

I overlooked this comment the first time I came to this question, the second time I looked at the [`GPGPreferences.m`](https://github.com/GPGTools/GPGPreferences_old/blob/master/GPGPreferences.m#L711) file, more specifically the `revealElementForKey` method but couldn't figure out how the function actually got called.

The keyword was `searchTerms`.

I only realized this when I finally found this article [SearchablePreferencePanes](http://cocoadev.com/SearchablePreferencePanes).

Steps:

1. Add a `NSPrefPaneSearchParameters` key to the `Info.plist` of your preference pane bundle with a value something like `MyPreferencePane`.
2. Create a file called `MyPreferencePane.searchTerms` in your Xcode project. The contents of this file should be a property list containing a dictionary that looks something like the one below (taken from the `Sound` preference pane). This will not only allow users to get a hit for your preference pane when searching for the specified terms, but it will also *generate the anchors for the preference pane*.
3. Implement the `revealElementForKey(key: String)` method in your class that inherits from `NSPreferencePane`. This method will be called both when the user opens the pane after searching for a term and also when calling the `reveal()` method for the ScriptingBridge anchor class.
4. Boom!

Enjoy life.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>effects</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localizableStrings</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>comments</key>
                <string>Localizable index words</string>
                <key>index</key>
                <string>noises, audio, hear, level, volume, louder, softer, quieter, increase, decrease, raise, lower, speaker, beep, warning, bell, ding, ring, hearing, beeping, dinging, ringing</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Alerts and sound effects</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>comments</key>
                <string>Localizable index words</string>
                <key>index</key>
                <string>audio, hear, level, volume, louder, softer, quieter, increase, decrease, raise, lower, music, speakers, hearing</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Sound volume</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>comments</key>
                <string>Localizable index words</string>
                <key>index</key>
                <string>audio, hear, level, volume, louder, softer, quieter, increase, decrease, raise, lower, quiet, silent, silence, turn off, hearing, muting</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Mute the sound</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>comments</key>
                <string>Localizable index words</string>
                <key>index</key>
                <string>menubar</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Show volume in menu bar</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>input</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localizableStrings</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>comments</key>
                <string>Localizable index words</string>
                <key>index</key>
                <string>audio, hear, level, volume, louder, softer, quieter, increase, decrease, raise, lower, devices, sources, microphones, instruments, MIDI, record, line in, hearing, recording</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Sound input</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
    <key>output</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localizableStrings</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>comments</key>
                <string>Localizable index words</string>
                <key>index</key>
                <string>devices, headphones, headsets, speakers, hear, balance, hearing, head phones, head sets</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>Sound output</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>comments</key>
                <string>Localizable index words</string>
                <key>index</key>
                <string>airplay, speakers</string>
                <key>title</key>
                <string>AirPlay audio streaming</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you must make sure that what you are searching is an anchor and not an other type of object.
Then use the script bellow to get every anchor names : (in this example get anchor of sound preferences will give "output", "input",..)

```
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
get the name of every anchor of current pane
end tell
```

Comment: I want to add an anchor to my own preference pane project.